# Are sarcastically funny comments allowed?

Tags: discussion, comments

Sometimes, when a particularly ridiculous question appears, a sarcastic joke can actually shed light on to the issue (by making the OP see how ridiculous the premise for the question is). They also can give some folks a good healthy laugh. However, these aren't the *niceset* way to communicate, and may potential offend the OP (In the case of some OPs, there is even a real risk they may take sarcasm for fact).

**Case Example:**

I wanted to post this:

> No it won't work, Microsoft completely re-worked its entire API, just to show software companies who is boss. However they didn't realize that everyone would just switch to their main competitor OS, windows 7.

as a comment to:
[Is Blender compatible with Windows 10?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33848/3127)

However I was afraid it may be deleted, or just isn't a good thing to say... Do we condone such comments?

*Bonus Question* Anyone think of a nicer way to make the joke?

Comment: I think we should, as this could be perceived as offensive. However, if written in a way that is obviously a joke, it should be fine.

Comment: I know! We can have SE build us a system where advanced users can write two messages, one for the author, and one for people above a certain amount of rep!

Comment: Well not a nice way to say it, but "It will never be compatible. In late 2014, Microsoft decided that they like to keep software companies in the dark, so they completely redid their software api so that no software company could ever write code for their Windows 10. This is why, I have switched to their main competitor, Windows 7."

Comment: What would a giant cow be doing asking about such an advanced subject as humor? All joking aside, there is nothing wrong with humor in the comments. (even if one of those nasty mods come along and deletes your comment as "too chatty" or "not funny" you really haven't lost anything.) However questions, answers are held to a different, and much higher standard. (I really tried to think of something funny to put in this)

Comment: Quite honestly, this may not be the right thing to do in light of @David's comment, but if I thought something was funny I would put it in an answer as well as a comment, I think the line isn't really a line, more like a gradient. as long as it's not a joke about someone, toward someone who has a history of being easily offended, or could be conceivably imagined to hurt someone, in my mind, it could belong either place. (I have no idea if that made sense or not)

Answer (score 10):

Well, we can't be serious *all* the time ;)

There is quite a lot of discussion about this on the [global meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152483/238438).
In general, humorous remarks are fine as long as they are relevant, not offensive, in good taste, and actually funny ;)

<sub>Of course, all these are highly subjective attributes. Such is humor.</sub>

Bonus points if your light-hearted comments also contribute useful and relevant information to the current discussion.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think sarcastic comments have a place on any SE site. For most people who ask questions here it's a one-off QA experience. We shouldn't be in the mind frame of thinking "they should know better than to ask a stupid question like that".

In the past it has happened that software written for a previous version of windows / OSX didn't work on the next version. Granted the way to solve it was often installing a system library or update the software to a compatible version. So *that* question isn't actually a demonstration of someone's ignorance. It's simply a question which deserves a respectful answer.

How difficult is it to answer (specifically to that question)

> " While currently windows 10 is a Beta edition, people have reported some issues to the bug tracker. As soon as Windows 10 reaches maturity (released to the public) we'll be able answer the question more authoritatively. It's in Microsoft's best interest to not break programs between upgrades, i'd be very surprised if Blender doesn't work on win 10 or can't be fixed specific to win 10 if it doesn't work immediately "

My biggest problem with sarcasm on a site like BSE is that the reader doesn't have the benefit of the cheeky glint in your eye as you give a nonsense answer. All they see is text, and are free to interpret your message in a way you didn't intend, not just because of language barriers, but someone can see it as a personal slight, especially if you haven't first built up rapport with them.